# SSRS not able to load images greater than 30k from Oracle Long Raw column

Tags: reporting-services, oracle11g, blob

I am using SSRS 2008 R2 to build reports and pulling data from Oracle 11g database. I have a long raw column which stores images. I use the report to render HTML on an aspx page.

The problem I face is when I store images greater than 30KB, SSRS does not pull the whole image, it shows only a broken image. But if i have any image less than or equal to 30KB the images load fine in the report. 
Is there any limitation in SSRS that can be changed ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the long-depricated `LONG RAW` to store the image rather than a `BLOB`?  The `LONG` and `LONG RAW` types were horrible mistakes made in Oracle 7 that were replace by `CLOB` and `BLOB` in Oracle 8.  Unless you somehow need Oracle 7 compatibility, the `LOB` API is much more robust (and much better supported by every possible client API) than `LONG RAW`.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the column to blob is not an option, I am working with a packaged software which chose to store the image like that. I am trying to build a report on top of it.